# "require ('org-journal')" creates "Symbol's value as variable is void: require"

Tags: init-file, variables

I added `require ('org-journal)` to my `.emacs`.
Now I get the error message: 'Symbol's value as variable is void: require', when emacs is started. Without `require ('org-journal)` there is no error message.
But Org Journal seems to work (even with the error message during the start): the key-binding `C-c C-j` for `org-journal-new-entry` works, but i get the message.

```
Source file ‘/home/nilss/.emacs.d/elpa/org-journal-1.12.0  
/org-journal.el’ newer than byte-compiled file
```

Output with `emacs --debug-init`:

```
[init-file-user system-type delayed-warnings-list user-init-file  
inhibit-default-init inhibit-startup-screen ms-dos "~" "/_emacs"  
windows-nt "/.emacs" directory-files nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$"   
        "~/.emacs" "^_emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" initialization format-message 
"`_emacs'   init file is deprecated, please use `.emacs'" "~/_emacs" t 
load expand-  file-name "init" file-name-as-directory "/.emacs.d" 
file-name-extension   "elc" file-name-sans-extension ".el" 
file-exists-p file-newer-than-file-p message "Warning: %s is newer than
 %s" sit-for 1 "default"] 7]()
```

I don't understand what this message wants to tell me.

Comment: try `(require 'org-journal)`

Comment: @JeanPierre: Please consider making that an answer, explaining things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the correct syntax, you should use:

```
(require 'org-journal)
```

In lisp syntax, this is the way to call the function `require` with argument `'org-journal`. On the other hand in:

```
require ('org-journal)
```

`require` is not at a place a function should be, so emacs thinks you talk about a *variable* with name `require` and this is exactly what

> Symbol's value as variable is void: require

is saying (ok, in a non totally obvious way for a beginner :-).

I would suggest you read at least the beginning of [Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/index.html) to get the basics of lisp.

Now, org-journal seems to work anyway.  Certainly something else forces its loading.  There may be other files loaded at startup as described in [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html#Init-File) section of emacs manual.

As for the message

> Source file ‘/home/nilss/.emacs.d/elpa/org-journal-1.12.0
>   /org-journal.el’ newer than byte-compiled file

`.el` files are emacs lisp source files, but for performance reasons emacs can also load *[byte-compiled](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html#Lisp-Libraries)* `.elc` files.  The message says it found both the source and the byte-compiled file (which is ok) but that the source is newer than the byte-compiled one (which suggests the source file has been changed but the compiled file has not been regenerated and so may be outdated).  Since you apparently installed `org-journal` from elpa, you could try to reinstall it with [`M-x list-package`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Packages.html#Packages).